# Codeigniter with ImageMagick

Tags: codeigniter, imagemagick

I understand that ImageMagick can be used with codeigniter. But where should I put the dll for imageMagick in the codeigniter folder? I am currently using codeiginiter on mac. I searched and got some answers in which imageMagick is installed in the bin folder. If I put the website live can I still use the ImageMagick?

My intention is to use ImageMagick to fetch some images and do overlaying to generate one image and save it. However when I try loading with the below code I got an error

```
    $config['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';
    echo site_url();
    $config['source_image'] = site_url().'marcella-resources/front/img/M24CPP_x200/SBase1.jpg';
    $config['new_image'] = site_url().'marcella-resources/front/test/SBase1_copy.jpg';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']     = 75;
    $config['height']   = 50;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);


    if ( !$this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        $this->image_lib->clear();
    }
```

The error is

```
The path to the image is not correct.

The path to your image library is not correct. Please set the correct path in your image preferences.
```

Comment: Maybe this one can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461783/resizing-an-image-on-the-fly-using-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Replace these lines:

```
$config['source_image'] = site_url().'marcella-resources/front/img/M24CPP_x200/SBase1.jpg';
$config['new_image'] = site_url().'marcella-resources/front/test/SBase1_copy.jpg';
```

with these lines:

```
$config['source_image'] = 'marcella-resources/front/img/M24CPP_x200/SBase1.jpg';
$config['new_image'] = 'marcella-resources/front/test/SBase1_copy.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your source image put Server root path and then full path to your folder. You can not use site url.

Put upload path as :

```
$upload_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."marcella-resources/front/img/M24CPP_x200/";
```

Then try this lines :

```
$config['source_image'] = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'marcella-resources/front/img/M24CPP_x200/SBase1.jpg';
$config['new_image'] = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'marcella-resources/front/test/SBase1_copy.jpg';
```

that will work absolutely. :)