# Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image

Tags: php, codeigniter

`Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.` is smashing my head. I don't understand which part is wrong! Path should be accurate.

Given that source image is **resources/images/upload/BAACN_13853.jpeg**

```
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){
    if($result[$i]['condition'] == "Success"){
        //**************** RESIZE *******************/

            $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
            $config['source_image'] = $result[$i]['msg'];
            $config['new_image'] = "/resources/images/upload_thumb/";
            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            if($width != NULL || $width != 0){
                $config['width'] = $width;
            }
            if($width != NULL || $width != 0){
                $config['height'] = $height;
            }

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

            if($this->image_lib->resize()){
                echo $result[$i]['msg']." resized successfully.<br>";
            }else{
                echo $result[$i]['msg']." resized failed!!<br>";
            };
            $this->image_lib->clear();
    }else{

        echo $result[$i]['msg']."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of server os do you have? You probably need to install php-gd module

Comment: I'm using WAMP on windows 7. How do I go about installing it?

Comment: By the way, it is already enabled.

Comment: On which line exactly does it throw exception? On $this->image_lib->resize()? Please add here resize() function body. Also please post here phpinfo() output.

Comment: Can you also show the HTML?

Comment: your folder is having permission to access

Answer (score 0):

To solve this removing the **forward slash** at the beginning in the following like so:

```
$config['source_image'] = $result[$i]['msg'];
$config['new_image'] = "/resources/images/upload_thumb/";
```

Make sure that **$result[$i]['msg']** doesn't begin with **forward slash**

Answer (score -1):

May be you are loading image_lib multiple times. Don't load image_lib multiple times. Add image_lib in autoload libs and change

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

to

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

Comment: You need to show reference of your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6684761/630979